# How to remove all current domain cookies in MVC website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on a MVC website, and in my logout link I want to remove all the current domain cookies.

I tried this:

```
this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Clear();
```

and this:

```
Response.Cookies.Clear();
```

but both didn't work and the cookies still there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you clear cookies using asp.net mvc 3 and c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122404/how-do-you-clear-cookies-using-asp-net-mvc-3-and-c)

Comment: I think that guy was only trying to delete one cookie. This guy wants to delete them all

Comment: Yes, I want to clear all cookies, not just one, deleting one cookie was fine, I am asking about deleting all domain cookies.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

How about this?

```
string[] myCookies = Request.Cookies.AllKeys;
foreach (string cookie in myCookies)
{
  Response.Cookies[cookie].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
}
```

Comment: @Swift, this deletes all the cookies for the main domain like "www.example.com". What if you want to delete all the cookies along with 
 sub domains like "abc.example.com" or "mobile.example.com" ?? Any idea.

Answer (score 1):

What about this ?

```
    if (Request.Cookies["cookie"] != null)
    {
        HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("cookie");
        myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
        Response.Cookies.Remove(myCookie);
    }
```

Comment: this is adding new cookies not removing the current, isn't?

Comment: so your idea is to add a new cookie with the same name as the existing one but with -1 day expiry?

Comment: @AmrElGarhy : I'm doing this now If you have any other better way to clear and update the cookies then please update the same

Comment: I am confused to why we create a new cookie with the same name and expiry it, instead of expiring the original one..

Answer (score 0):

```
myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
```

This does not clear the cookies instantly.

You can use:

```
myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(1);
```

To clear cookies instantly