# How to clear cookie in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies

I have tried the following but, the cookie is not expired after the given time.
Can you please look into my code

```
System.Web.HttpCookie currentUserCookie = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["Userdata"];
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Remove("Userdata");
currentUserCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10);
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you want to clear it or set it to expire 10 mins in the future?

Comment: i want to expire the cookie after 10 mins.. after that userdata must be null

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219068/how-do-i-manually-delete-a-cookie-in-asp-net-mvc-4

Comment: cookie automatically expires on page load. how can i prevent that ?

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to use the Response object to write back to the browser:

```
if ( Request.Cookies["MyCookie"] != null )
{
    var c = new HttpCookie( "MyCookie" );
    c.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays( -1 );
    Response.Cookies.Add( c );
}
```

More information on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178195.aspx

Comment: i want to clear cookie after 10 minutes. how can i use this ?

Comment: or can we set expire time to zero aftre the cookie expired

Comment: @RahulBridge, that's what the Cookie.Expires do, you can set whatever expiration time you want to set. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122404/how-do-you-clear-cookies-using-asp-net-mvc-3-and-c

Comment: after clearing cookies im getting like this
Domain: null
    Expires: {0001-01-01 00:00:00}
    HasKeys: false
    HttpOnly: false
    Name: "Userdata"
    Path: "/"
    Secure: false
    Shareable: false
    Value: ""
    Values: {} 

I need to check if the cookie is expired i want to return null . So how can i check that ?? if iam clearing cookie

Comment: is there any way to set null in the 
"Expires" to null when the cookie is expired. so i can check with this value

Comment: you can check whether cookie is null OR not like  `if (controller.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[cookieName] == null)
            return;`

Comment: cookie automatically expires on page load. how can i prevent that ?

Comment: @RahulBridge Means I didn't get you ?

Comment: if i set 5 mins to cookie, it will showing that cookie will expires
Expires: {3/23/2017 11:28:23 AM}.
but after that on page load
 Expires: {0001-01-01 00:00:00}. This is the problem

Comment: you should add the cookie in HttpResponse object while creating it, if not obviously you will not get it. it doesn't matter how many times you load the page within that stipulated time, only on load you should check whether cookie is null OR not else create a new cookie