# Save localization in Cookies or in Session (ASP.Net MVC 3)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my ASP.Net MVC 3 application I have implement localization. I save localization of user in cookies. In my application I have autentification. What is the best way saving localization in cookies or in session (session is 2880 seconds as in `web.config` and after this tyme user should again chouse it's language in application)

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5122611/558018) answer might help on adding cookies to the client's cookie store.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ASP.NET Session and cookies depends on browser so when user changes the browser he will have to select language again. You may create a setting in database and allow user to select language in profile. In this case you he will not need to reselect language each time he changes a browser.

At the same time you may use cookies to store language locally so when user is not logged in language from cookies will be applied.

Answer (score 1):

LocalStorage is a great place to store application settings that you'd like to persist between sessions (as opposed to sessionStorage) and not be transmitted to the server (as opposed to a cookie). Previously, to avoid having cookie based settings transmitted to the server needlessly, you'd have to use a different subdomain just for cookies.

Comment: Local storage is with html5 here a example http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_webstorage.asp