# Logout link with return URL (OAuth)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0, logout, google-oauth

My application is integrated with Facebook, Google and Microsoft (using OAuth).

To logout from facebook I'm using the following URL:

```
https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=[YourAppURL]&access_token=[ValidAccessToken]
```

Is there something similar for Google and for Microsoft?

For Google I tried:

```
https://accounts.google.com/Logout?continue=http://localhost:51820
```

But it didn't work... It returns: `The page you requested is invalid.`

How can I get that URL logout?

Comment: Do you use OAuth for client-side (only JavaScript integration) or server-side (with the access codes and token exchange on your server)? Note that for server-side case, it is wrong to expose access-token to the client-side. Facebook provides no proper way to logout users who where authorized via server-side.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I finally got the right links:

- Facebook:

`https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=[YourAppURL]&access_token=[ValidAccessToken]`

Source: [A Working Facebook OAuth Logout URL](http://keganzo.blogspot.pt/2012/03/working-facebook-oauth-logout-url.html)

- Google:

`https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout?continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/logout?continue=[http://www.mysite.com]`

Source: [google account logout and redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14831349/1204249)

- Microsoft:

`https://login.live.com/oauth20_logout.srf?client_id=[CLIENT_ID]&redirect_uri=[REDIRECT_URL]`

Source: [Server-side scenarios](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243649.aspx)

Those links can be use like that in JavaScript:

```
function logout (){
document.location.href = "https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=[YourAppURL]&access_token=[ValidAccessToken]";
}
```

Suggestion to implement this: [Logout from external login service (Gmail, facebook) using oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17127549/1204249)

Comment: hi @amp tried with your Google sample it works fine! Do u have same for LinkedIn account...?

Comment: Thanks man. I wasted half my day finding the solution to redirect back to my home instead of Google login. This really worked.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be logging the user out of Facebook, Google, etc. You just need to log them out of *your app*. By redirecting them to `accounts.google.com/Logout` you're actually logging the user out of their *Google* account, which means if they also had Gmail open in another tab (say) they'd also be logged out of that. Similarly, if you redirect them to `www.facebook.com/logout.php` you're actually logging them out of *Facebook*, which means if they had Facebook open in another tab, they would be logged out of there as well.

Instead, all you should do, when the user logs out of your app, is "forget" the OAuth tokens.

Comment: I know that, but I'm asking first if they really want logout from the provider. This could be useful, for instance, in a public computer.

Comment: Actually facebook states it in their policies that you MUST logout users from facebook as well if you offer "logout" button on your application. Unfortunately, they do not provide a correct way to do this if users have been authorized on the server-side.

Comment: I allow login to a single account on my site through both username/password and social media. If you edit your account to change your password, and you logged in with username/password, you need to provide your old password (i.e. re-authenticate). If you logged in through Facebook, you should be required to re-authenticate with Facebook. But the only way to do that is to force logout from Facebook - if you don't, the Oauth authentication just succeeds immediately because your session is still logged in to facebook.