# ASP.net identity - external login - won't log out

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

In my application, all my *authentication* happens with Google - ie - all my users are Google Accounts.

I don't need users to need to register in my app, just sign in using a Google account.  However, I do want to manage Roles for the users with ASP.net Identity (*I think*)

With that in mind, on successful external authentication, I create an ASP.net Identity user (if one doesn't exist)

So, I've got my ExternalLoginCallback as follows:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
        var authenticationManager = Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication;

        var loginInfo = await authenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();

        //successfully authenticated with google, so sign them in to our app
        var id = new ClaimsIdentity(loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.Claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        authenticationManager.SignIn(id);

        //Now we need to see if the user exists in our database
        var user = UserManager.FindByName(loginInfo.Email);

        if (user == null)
        {
            //user doesn't exist, so the user needs to be created
            user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = loginInfo.Email, Email = loginInfo.Email };

            await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);

            //add the google login to the newly created user
            await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, loginInfo.Login);
        }

        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }
```

Idea being, I can now manage users, add roles, check if users are in roles, etc....

Firstly, is this a sensible approach? Or have I over complicated it?

One issue I'm having, however, is with logging out of my application

My `Logout` action looks like:

```
public ActionResult LogOut()
{
    HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut();

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

My Index action is decorated with the [Authorize] attribute - 
However, when I 'logout' - it redirects to Home.Index - but I still seem to be logged in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [ASPNet Identity Work Item](https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/workitem/1942), this is by design, and you need to call directly to Google's API in order to log the user out.

Comment: that's the thing - i don't actually want to log out of Google, just my application....

Comment: hmm...once you perform that logout, does the cookie get removed?

Answer (score 1):

completing the post [Logout link with return URL (OAuth)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17050575/logout-link-with-return-url-oauth)
Here is a solution that work for me :

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return Redirect("https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout?continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/logout?continue=https://[url-of-your-site]");
    }
```

Comment: Well really no. That logs out the user from his google profile completely. It's not logging the app out.