# GIDSignIn require password

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

I'm developing an internal app that will leverage our corporate Google Drive accounts and will be used on shared devices (iPads shared among teachers and students at school sites).

Is there a way to force `GIDSignIn` to require a password with each sign-in attempt? Right now, even after calling `GIDSIgnIn.sharedInstance().signOut()` (or `GIDSignIn.sharedInstacne().disconnect()`) the user doesn't need to enter their password the next time they access the app. That means, when the device is taken by the next user, they could very easily access the other user's account.

Am I missing something? Do I need to somehow clear the cookies store in the `UIWebView` that the `GIDSignIn` process uses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where available, the `GIDSignIn` login process uses a `SFSafariViewController`,  not a `UIWebView`. It leverages the cookies (as well as passwords) stored in Safari, for a quicker login.

I don't think you would be able to clear such cookies. You should be able to force a Google log out, though, by opening `https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout` in an `SFSafariViewController`, though the interaction with the rest of your app may be a bit weird. See [Logout link with return URL (OAuth)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17050575/logout-link-with-return-url-oauth) for a way to provide a return URL which you may try to use to control the process (you'll need to use an URL scheme to return, though).

Note that iOS may prompt to save login information, and then provide said login information to subsequent users. You'll need to disable that in Settings -> Safari -> AutoFill

There may be other ways of achieving it via configuration of the device, but iOS is not really designed for multiple users at the moment.